# David Copperfield by Charles Dickens

Tags: meaning-in-context

would you be able to explain me the following line from the end of the Chapter one? Especially the bold part. Thanks Guys. You are all genius :)

> No. I lay in my basket, and my mother lay in her bed;
>   **but Betsey Trotwood Copperfield was for ever in the land of
>   dreams and shadows, the tremendous region whence I had
>   so lately travelled; and the light upon the window of our
>   room shone out upon the earthly bourne of all such travellers,
>   and the mound above the ashes and the dust that once
>   was he, without whom I had never been.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the site doesn't offer critical analyses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*but Betsey Trotwood Copperfield was for ever in the land of dreams and shadows*: I suppose this bit refers to fact that she left David because he didn't turn out to be a girl. So she becomes unreal to him.

*the tremendous region whence I had so lately travelled*: I'd guess this refers to David's existence before being born, when he was unreal.

*and the light upon the window of our room shone out upon the earthly bourne of all such travellers, and the mound above the ashes and the dust that once was he, without whom I had never been*: and this last bit would seem to refer to David's father, who died before he was born. The word *bourne* means "destination, goal," the *earthly* goal of all human travelers being death/the grave, under which lies David's father, "without whom [David] had never been," never have existed.

Comment: I took this to be a question as to semantics--sense and reference/meaning, not interpretation. The answer was framed as such.